# Format content when it gets copied to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, css

Some content on my website appears slightly strange when copied and pasted into a rich text editor like Gmail.

Is it possible to somehow affect the formatting when a user copies content?

As a simple example, suppose I have this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
h1 { color: red; }
p {size: small; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>My Title</h1>
<p>The body of the text.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Is it possible to have the title appear green when you copy paste all the contents?

Comment: What content gets copied to the rich text editor? Only the html? Inline styles? Style tags?

Comment: I don't think this is possible to edit get the copied text from clipboard using javascript on all browsers, but may be something like this lib helps  https://clipboardjs.com/

Comment: Gmail will keep inline styling rules on elements whey you copy/paste from the net. It also has the ability to read the applying rules on an element and selectively apply the ones it deems likely to have been intended. The only way to control it is by trial and error and, or course, it is not guaranteed to work tomorrow, as it's proprietary - not a standard. It changes all the time and it will change in the future. The simplest way to achieve what you want is `style="color:green"` on element and, if it shouldn't be green in the page, use a stronger selector in `CSS` than the inline rule.